# C++ - Having Linux terminal tab function as a input method inside the program

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

So I was writing a simple c++ program and I want to have the "tab" function to show directories instead of manually typing in the directory in the terminal as input.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Basically after starting the program I want it to read the terminal for any input and in that input I want to have the "shell function" which can auto-complete/suggest directories.

Edit: Readline looks promising from what I have read. I will try it out when I have time and leave feedback.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Inside or outside of your program?

Comment: You may want to use [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

Comment: Autocompletion is _not_ a function of the terminal. It is a function of the _shell_ or of some other program. Read the documentation of your shell to learn how autocompletion is implemented and, if desired, reuse the implementation.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, I will/have updated my question.